# Bash command in php script, get some lines of a file according values of a specific column

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, grep

Via linux bash command(s) (grep + regex + another commands ?) from a php script, I want get the line(s) of a file according some conditions, see below :

**An exemple of a file :**

```
"id_line1","value_line1_column2","foo blablabla","value_line1_column4" 
"id_line2","value_line2_column2","blablabla foo","value_line2_column4"
"id_line3","value_line3_column2","blabla foo blabla","value_line3_column4"
"id_line4","value_line4_column2","blablabla","value_line4_column4"
"id_line5","value_line5_column2","fooblabla bla","value_line5_column4"
"id_line6","value_line6_column2","blabla blafoo","value_line6_column4"
"id_line7","value_line7_column2","blabla foobla bla","value_line7_column4"
```

I want search only on the column number X in the file ( the third column in this example ).

**The regular expression**

In the third column of all lines of my file, I want find string(s) containing a searched word that is : (via grep + regex ?)

- At the beginning of the string of the specific column (here in the example, the third column)
- OR at the end of the string of the specific column (here in the example, the third column)
- OR somewhere in the string of the specific column (here in the example, the third column)

And find only the word not concatenated with another words. By example, with the example file above, if I search the word "foo" :

```
"id_line1","value_line1_column2","foo blablabla","value_line1_column4" // the regex must return true
"id_line2","value_line2_column2","blablabla foo","value_line2_column4" // the regex must return true
"id_line3","value_line3_column2","blabla foo blabla","value_line3_column4" // the regex must return true
"id_line4","value_line4_column2","blablabla","value_line4_column4" // the regex must return false
"id_line5","value_line5_column2","fooblabla bla","value_line5_column4" // the regex must return false
"id_line6","value_line6_column2","blabla blafoo","value_line6_column4" // the regex must return false
"id_line7","value_line7_column2","blabla foobla bla","value_line7_column4" // the regex must return false
```

**The result**

Command(s) must return lines :

```
"id_line1","value_line1_column2","foo blablabla","value_line1_column4"
"id_line2","value_line2_column2","blablabla foo","value_line2_column4"
"id_line3","value_line3_column2","blabla foo blabla","value_line3_column4"
```

How can I do this ? 
If I can only get the id ("id_line1", "id_line2", "id_line3") it would be perfect :)

Comment: Could you put an example of the data you would be looking for and the result expected.

Comment: I put an example of data in the post , and the result expected according some conditions explained. Can you explain what do you need ? :)

Comment: You are focusing on column 2 and then say that you want output relating to line 1,2 and 3. What is the regular expression to attain these results? All  of the data in column 2 is the same apart from the numbers at the end of the line1 text. The post is very unclear.

Comment: I think I get it, when I speak about column 2 , I mean the third column (for the line 1 in my example, column 0 is "id_line1", column 1 is "value_line1_column1" , column 2 is "foo blablabla", column 3 is "value_line1_column3"). Ill edit my post for precise this point, sorry !  So, I want get line(s) of my file according values contained in the third column for each lines.

Comment: OK but you are still unclear on the regular expression. It looks like you are looking for one foo and 3 blah entries but line 3 has 4?

Comment: the third column of the line 3 is "blabla foo blabla". This string contains the word 'foo' and 'foo' isn't concatenated with another word, the regex must return this line. However, the third column of the line 4 is "blablabla" , "blablabla" doens't contain the word "foo", therefore the regex doesn't return the line 4. In brief, if the string contains at least one word "foo" (and "foo" is an entire word, "foo" isn't included in another word), the regex must returns the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Awk will do the job:

```
awk -F, '$3 ~ /"foo / || $3 ~ / foo"/ || $3 ~ /[[:blank:]]foo[[:blank:]]/ { print $0 }' filename
```

Here we are checking the third piece of each line delimited by , and checking for "foo or ( signified by ||) a blank space and then foo and then another blank space and finally foo". If any of these occurances occur, print the line

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you :) If somebody wants add insensitive search and get only the first column (the id column in my example), you can use : awk -F, '{IGNORECASE = 1} $5 ~ /"foo / || $5 ~ / foo"/ || $5 ~ /[[:blank:]]foo[[:blank:]]/ { print $1 }' filename